# Elm cannot find Module that is in a dependancy

Tags: elm

Here is my project's elm-package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "summary": "helpful summary of your project, less than 80 characters",
  "repository": "https://github.com/user/project.git",
  "license": "BSD3",
  "source-directories": [
      "."
  ],
  "exposed-modules": [],
  "dependencies": {
    "elm-lang/core": "5.1.1 <= v < 6.0.0",
    "elm-lang/html": "2.0.0 <= v < 3.0.0",
    "simonh1000/elm-charts": "3.1.0 <= v < 4.0.0"
  },
  "elm-version": "0.18.0 <= v < 0.19.0"
}
```

`elm-charts` exports a module called `Chart`.

In my `ChartView.elm` I want to import `Chart`

```
module Components.ChartView exposing ( .. )

import Chart as C exposing ( .. )
import Html exposing ( Html, div )
import Html.Attributes exposing ( id, class )
```

but when elm tries to compile, I get the error:

```
I cannot find module 'Chart'.

Module 'Components.ChartView' is trying to import it.

Potential problems could be:   * Misspelled the module name   * Need
to add a source directory or new dependency to elm-package.json
```

if I open elm repl from the project directory, I can import Chart as expected:

```
jon@jon-Xubuntu-VB:~/elixir/eval$ elm repl
\> import Chart
\>
```

any ideas why I Elm can't 'find Chart' when compiling?

Comment: Is `ChartView.elm` in a subdirectory, or is it sitting there next to `elm-package.json`? Is it possible for you to link your Git repo so we can clone it and have a look?

Comment: have you ran `elm-package install -y` so that the library is downloaded?

Comment: Yes, I did elm-package install. The module is available in the repl, when opened from the project's top level directory

Comment: Simon, yes it is in a sub-directory. In new to elm, so was not aware this could be an issue

Comment: @RyanPlant, this was the problem.  This is a Phoenix project and I had my elm project in ./web/elm.  The package was installed in in ./elm-stuff when it needed to be installed in ./web/elm/elm-stuff.  Not sure how I ended up with an `elm-package.json` file in the phoenix app's top level directory.  If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this has been resolved in comments, no one has written this in an answer yet.
Elm will not find dependencies from nested directories: you want to run `elm repl` in the same directory as your `elm-package.json` (adjacent to the `elm-stuff` directory). It sounds like you mistakenly have an `elm-package.json` file at the top level of your app, when you wanted it in the `web/elm/` directory.

Comment: this is a gratuitous answer but I figured we could save people from looking into this question thinking it's unanswered.